# Uninstalling GRUB from MacBook Air

Tags: 12.04, grub2, mac, macbook-air

I have a MacBook Air and I recently tried to install Ubuntu on my external HD. I booted Ubuntu from a flash drive and everything had gone fine. I turned off my computer and when I turned it on again I got a message of error and a "grub rescue" line to enter some code. I rebooted holding the "option" key and I selected the Mac partition and everything is fine with my system, but every time I start my system and I don't hold the "option" key, I get the same error and the grub rescue message. I just want things to go back to normal, as they were before I installed Ubuntu on my external HD (which, btw, presented a message that said there was no boot loader). What do I do?

Comment: Can you boot into Ubuntu?

Comment: No... I didn't install Ubuntu on my Mac, only on my external hd, and as I said, it didn't work, because when I connected my external hd in the other computer, it said there was no boot loader. Then I formatted my external hd. I can boot into Ubuntu with a flash drive, but I'm gonna have to do one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe holding control in the mac boot loader makes that choice the default, this will save you from messing with the 'bless' command.